# SOAP Backend System for Push Notification

Tags: soap, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, backend

I have an application that gets the user's location using Worklight's Location Service API. Once the user enters a region, I want the user to receive a push notification. I understand that push notifications are sent from a backend server. However, I don't know  how to create the backend server. Based on the tutorials from IBM, I discovered that SOAP can be one of the back end. I want to ask if SOAP can serve as a backend server for sending push notification? If yes, how do I implement this? Sorry, I'm not familiar with SOAP.  Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: SOAP is not a server.

Comment: Read: https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fadmin%2Fc_push_notification_possible_architectures.html

Comment: oh. The document did not mention any backend that can be used except for JMS that is used for polling. But, I dont want to use polling method for pushing notification. Can you suggest any backend to implement sending of push notification?

Comment: Writing a back-end to your application is a huge task and if you haven't already got one I would strongly recommend reviewing your requirements. If you still want the back-end you need to start looking at where your webservice will be hosted, who will create you webservice, how will you create your webservice (Java, PHP etc), what will your webservice do. If you are creating a webservice you will probably need to create a WSDL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) As for SOAP this is just a way of communicating between application and webservice this is not a backend

Answer (score 2):

The back-end of your application can be exposed/consumed in what way you want; SOAP, REST, etc.

The push notification works (as you said) from server (in WL using WL.Server.notify methods) to (subscribed) client (in WL using WL.Client.Push methods). 
Now you have to think of a way of 'telling' the WL server to send the push to the (subscribed) clients when a user enters a region - e.g. by estimating when the client enters that region or by sending the location to the server (in background) and then a back-end server determine the fact that the user entered a region.

So, you'd have:
1. back-end location estimator <-> WL Server -> Push provider -> client
2. client -> WL Server -> back-end service that determines if the location is in a new region -> WL Server -> Push provider -> client.

Push notifications are done using Apple (Apple Push Notification Service), Google (Google Cloud Messaging), Microsoft infrastructures - each one has it's own way of doing that.

Take a look to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_notif to see how Push Notification works in Worklight.